# How to add admob on firebase listview UI

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database, admob, firebaseui

I am trying to add admod to firebase listview in which after every 6 items there is an ad.Is this possible using a listview firebase ui?

An example code is as follows

```
listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Getters>(
            this,
            Getters.class,
            R.layout.search_layout,
            retrieveFollowers
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, final Getters model, int position) {

            final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();

            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
            username.setText(model.getUsername());
            TextView names = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            names.setText(model.getName());
            ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewProfile);
            Picasso.with(Followers.this).load(model.getProfileImage()).transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4)).centerCrop().fit().into(profileImage);

        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

I wanted to put an ad where after every 6th follower there is an ad(This is just an example).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Adapter's getView method, you can add ads by checking positions like this.

```
   if(position % 6 ==0){

      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_native_ad, parent, false);
      NativeExpressAdView nativeAdView = (NativeExpressAdView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nativeAdView);
      nativeAdView.setAdUnitId("Your Ad id here");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .build();
        nativeAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
   } else {
      // add your view here
   }
```

Refer this Git Demo https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter. This will help you.It shows you how to implement ads in listview with your adapter.

Comment: Please, [no link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)...

Comment: Did not understand well, maybe rewrite my code and add admob features and i could understand